# WAMP server was pointing to IP address, IP address has now changed. I can no longer access my site

Tags: server, wamp, internals

When setting up WAMP I could not use localhost because of many errors. So I pointed it specifically to an IP address everything worked great for 1 year, we have moved and now have a new IP.
Where is it that I have to change info to new IP address?

Comment: Whereever you changed it before is the obvious answer. Its not real clear what you have done here so not so easy to guess where you may have changed something to frig the system

Comment: Why not localhost? And What errors??